# Android Key Events for EditText not happening on device

Tags: android, event-handling, android-edittext

I am new to Android development and having a problem with what SHOULD be a very simple task. I want to receive KeyEvents whenever a user is typing in an EditText field because I want to save their entered values to data structures in the background on each key stroke.

I have mimic'd the code in the Beginner's Dev guide at http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#EditText and set up an OnKeyListener. Here is a snippet of my code:

`cell.amountEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {`

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    System.err.println("onKey for Amount, key="+event.getDisplayLabel());
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        return onKeyDownInAmount(finalPosition, (EditText)v, keyCode, event);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

});

Behavior on the emulator is spotty at best, some times it will deliver the KeyEvents for the virtual keyboard, sometimes it won't. When I install the app on my device (HTC Hero which has a virtual keyboard only) then NONE of the events fire. I never receive a single KeyEvent.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The onKeyListener only receives events from a hardware keyboard.  Use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. I have no idea why the Android Developer Guide said to use the key listener on the Form Stuff page!

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely confusing.